# Подключение к web-камере. Нужен совет

Tags: java, opencv

Подскажите как можно получить доступ к web-камере? В какую сторону смотреть? Возможно есть готовые библиотеки? Если есть, та какая из них самая простая? Такие монстры как OPENCV Processing and Java Library не подходят, в виду своей громоздкости. Нашёл OpenCV. Но вот как использовать для ip камер примеров не нашёл. Примеры для подключения к камере ноута одни. Спасибо. Камера D-link DCS-930
Кто подскажет, почему не проходит данный код:

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture ip_cam = new VideoCapture();

    ip_cam.open("http://login:password@ip_adres/video/mjpg.cgi");

    if (!ip_cam.isOpened())
    {
        System.out.print("Error while trying to open the webcam\n");
        return;
    }


    System.out.println("Success!");

    ip_cam.release();
```

Если заходить через браузер, то пускает, но выдает окно где спрашивает что действительно ли я захожу под login-oм указанным в строке. Может из-за этого не срабатывает код?

Comment: Насколько я помню, камера общается с устройствами посредством протокола tcp:81, попробуйте капнуть глубже в этом направлении

Comment: попробуйте указывать номер порта при подключении, например IpCam.open("http://192.168.1.30:8080/?dummy=param.mjpg");